# Optimizing an SQL query with AVG operations for a Azure CosmosDB

Tags: sql, azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a large amount of sensor data (many GB) saved in an Azure CosmosDB. The data looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": "41322a50-a5ba-41a5-97cf-1b3c26e0b0f8",
    "Time": 637591000753940400,
    "Temperature": 21.338543,
    "Humidity": 51.168198,
    "Pressure": 997.39777,
    "PM10": 17,
    "PM2_5": 17,
    "PM1": 12,
    "Lux": 91.6434,
}
```

I have the following SQL query that uses this sensor data:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.Time) as Items, AVG(c.Temperature) as Temperature, AVG(c.Humidity) as Humidity, AVG(c.Lux) as Lux, AVG(c.PM10) as PM10, AVG(c.PM2_5) as PM2_5, AVG(c.PM1) as PM1 
FROM SensorData c 
WHERE c.Time BETWEEN @startTime AND @endTime
```

Basically the `AVG` function is used a lot. My goal is to optimize this query. I am aware that I could cache results / etc. but I want see how far I can get without building additional infrastructure.

I read some docs on indexes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#queries-with-a-filter-and-an-aggregate
based on that I created the following indexing policy:

```json
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ],
    "compositeIndexes": [
        [
            {
                "path": "/Time",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Temperature",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "path": "/Time",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Humidity",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "path": "/Time",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Lux",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "path": "/Time",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/PM10",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "path": "/Time",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/PM2_5",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "path": "/Time",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/PM1",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "path": "/Time",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/Pressure",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Sadly, testing my query (on a 500MB subset of the data) still shows a very large index lookup time:
[image: Azure stats]

Can my indexing policy be improved? Are there any other strategies that could improve the performance of my specific query?

Comment: How many observations were averaged in the example you showed? Does the index lookup time increase if you include a wider time range? Your index looks like it covers your query correctly. But keep in mind that there's no magic here: whether the software gets its data from an index or the data store itself, it still must look at every observation to get the averages you want. Three seconds for such an aggregate query is reasonable.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks for your response, the query always takes between 1500 to 4500 ms. It does not matter how much data is in the specified time span, for example 10 elements took 1800 ms and 500000 elements took 3800 ms. I guess the time is indeed acceptable, but just above of what I need for my use case (real time chart generation, with zoom and pan).